# How to center and left-align an enumeration environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I have a simple enumeration list as below. I want to center it with everything left-aligned but I couldn't do it. Is there an easy way to do so? Many thanks.

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item[(i)] $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.

\item[(ii)] $A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$,

$A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.

\item[(iii)] $(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,

$(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$

\item[(iv)] $A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,

$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you mean an enumerate  environment which is *globally centred*, , but left-aligned inside the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest with a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,tabstackengine}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Standard enumerate
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]

\item $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.

\item $A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$,

$A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.

\item $(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,

$(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$

\item $A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,

$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$
\end{enumerate}

Tabular:\\
\setstackgap{L}{14pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.85}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\centerline{\begin{tabular}{rl}
(i) &              $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.\\
(ii) &  \Longunderstack[l]{$A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$\\
                   $A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.}\\
(iii) & \Longunderstack[l]{$(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,\\
                   $(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$}\\
(iv) &  \Longunderstack[l]{$A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,\\
                   $A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$}
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately with a TABstack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,tabstackengine}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Standard enumerate
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]

\item $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.

\item $A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$,

$A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.

\item $(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,

$(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$

\item $A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,

$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$
\end{enumerate}

TABstack:\\
\setstackgap{S}{12pt}
\setstackgap{L}{14pt}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\centerline{\tabularShortunderstack{rl}{
(i) &               $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.\\
(ii) &  \stackunder{$A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$}
                   {$A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.}\\
(iii) & \stackunder{$(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,}
                   {$(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$}\\
(iv) &  \stackunder{$A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,}
                   {$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
\begin{varwidth}{\displaywidth}
\begin{enumerate}

\item[(i)] $\neg (\neg A)\equiv A$.

\item[(ii)] $A\vee B\equiv B\vee A$,

$A\wedge B\equiv B\wedge A$.

\item[(iii)] $(A\vee B)\vee C\equiv A\vee(B\vee C)$,

$(A\wedge B)\wedge C\equiv A\wedge(B\wedge C)$

\item[(iv)] $A\vee(B\wedge C)\equiv (A\vee B)\wedge (A\vee C)$,

$A\wedge(B\vee C)\equiv (A\wedge B)\vee (A\wedge C)$

\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
\]
\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]